# Can you "reset" amiibo level data?

Tags: amiibo

All question is basically already in title: is it possible to reset data accumulated in amiibo, and start leveling it from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as of Wii U software update 5.3.0, the System Settings app has an Amiibo section, including two ways to remove data stored on the figure's chip:

- [Erase Game Data](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13179?a_id=13167&~=how-to-set-up%2C-reset%2C-and-configure-amiibo&session=f_1ylB9m) - Removes the game-specific data from the figure.
- [Reset Amiibo](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13180?a_id=13167&~=how-to-set-up%2C-reset%2C-and-configure-amiibo&session=f_1ylB9m) - Removes all data: the game-specific data, and the figure's nickname and owner.

Sounds like you're looking for the first one.

Comment: Thanks! I guess both potions are useful, second in case if you want to sell figurine, for example.